# Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found". Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Can someone please enlighten me what causing this problem in symfony and how to solve it.

> Oops! An Error Occurred  The server returned a "404 Not Found".

I'm just new in symfony and cpanel.

I just uploaded my working SF application from my pc (localhost) to my server or `CPANEL`. CPanel doesn't have `SSH access` so I used FTP to upload all directories. The directory of the files like so.

home/swipecom

- cache
- **contactless (Where SF directories live)**
- **public_html (/web the only SF directory)**
- var
- ssl
- tmp
- public_ftp
- logs

I created `.htaccess` into `public_html` like so `public_html/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /web

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Lastly, I configured `app.php` in something like this.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */

// $loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
// include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$loader = require '/home2/swipecom/contactless/app/autoload.php';
include_once '/home2/swipecom/contactless/var/bootstrap.php.cache';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

When I try to access the app like so `www.domain.com` here's the response I received.

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

**UPDATE**

routing.yml

```
route_frontend:
    resource: "@SwipeBundle/Resources/config/routing_frontend.yml"

route_backend:
    resource: "@SwipeBundle/Resources/config/routing_backend.yml"

route_security:
    resource: "@SwipeBundle/Resources/config/routing_security.yml"
```

routing_dev.yml

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

AppKernel.php

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            //  new SunCat\MobileDetectBundle\MobileDetectBundle(),
            new SwipeBundle\SwipeBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

`.htaccess` inside `web` directory

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_alias.c>
       RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
   </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It looks working, do you any route registered to your application?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I added my routing above.

Comment: Before uploading did you generate the production cache?  If so, change new AppKernel('prod', false); to new AppKernel('prod', true); to possibly get a better error message.  And check to see if your host has any instructions concerning symfony.  There are often directory permission issues.

Comment: before uploading I just run this command `./bin/console cache:clear --env=prod & ./bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`,

Answer (score -1):

I think this is tutorial help you:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

[Enabling mod_rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

```
.htaccess
```

.htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_alias.c>
       RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
   </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Do I have to override the .htaccess inside `web` directory?

Comment: @phpmeter this .htaccess file inside web directory.

Comment: I do update the .htaccess inside my `web` directory, but same problem.